# Cast Enum to return Generic C# 7.3

Tags: c#, generics, c#-7.3

More than probably this is a conceptual misunderstood but I want to know why.

I've a static method that can return one generic value T, and it also receives a string.

```
public static T GetWordType<T>(string word) where T : System.Enum
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ActionType))
    {
        foreach (Word<ActionType> action in actionsList)
        {
            if (action.synonims.Contains(word))
                return action.type;
        }
        return ActionType.None;
    }
    return WordType.None;
}
```

All returns gives me a cast error with the title "You cannot convert implicitly Action.ActionType to T".

Why?

My Action class is declared inheriting from an abstract Word Class defined as follows:

```
public abstract class Word<T> where T : System.Enum
{
    public List<string> synonims;
    public T type;
}
```

I'm clearly messing and overcomplicating this up, but I can't figure it out how should be implemented. Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**: As a petition from Pavel Anikhouski
my ActionType enum is declared inside Action class like this:

```
class Action : Word<ActionType>
{
    public enum ActionType
    {
        Open, Close, Shutdown, Stop, Send, Save, Load, Move, Add, Cancel, None
    }
}
```

and my WordType enum is a test enum, could be any enum at this moment, is just set it to test the returning of different enums. Something like:

```
public enum WordType
{
    None, Test
}
```

Comment: Why do think that's allowed? `T` can be any enum type in `GetWordType<T>` method. And why do you return `ActionType.None` and `WordType.None` inside and outside `if` statement? Please, share `ActionType` and `WordType` enums

Comment: Done. Clearly it's not allowed, but in my head sounds like it's allowed cause in any case I'm returning an Enum value, which fits my "conception" of what a Generic value is.

Comment: The generic parameters are specified at compile time. There is covariance and contravariance, but this would not work with value types (like enum) since they can't extend from each other. If it is possible to change to `foreach (Word<T> action in actionsList)`, and you can `return default(T);` which would work in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this when I take out what’s inside of your `if`:

```
public static T GetWordType<T>(string word) where T : System.Enum
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ActionType))
    { … }

    return ActionType.Cancel;
}
```

As you can see, you check whether `T` is `ActionType`. If it is *not*, then you return `ActionType.Cancel` which obviously is an `ActionType`. But your method is supposed to return `T` which you have just proven *not* to be `ActionType`.

So instead of `T`, you actually want your method to return `ActionType` in all cases because that’s exactly what you are doing:

```
public static ActionType GetWordType<T>(string word) where T : System.Enum
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ActionType))
    {
        foreach (Word<ActionType> action in actionsList)
        {
            if (action.synonims.Contains(word))
                return action.type;
        }
        return ActionType.None;
    }
    return ActionType.Cancel;
}
```

And at this point one could argue that you don’t even need a generic method here because you are not really doing much with that parameterized type `T` other than checking for its exact type.

It’s generally a bad idea to deal with actual possible types for `T` inside generic methods. It makes your method, which is supposed to be generic for *all* compatible types, brittle since you are looking for exact types but actually deal with an infinite number of types `T` that you cannot plan for.

---

You have since changed your question so that it returns `ActionType.None` inside of the `if` and `WordType.None` outside of the condition. You are still returning concrete types so you cannot have your method return `T`. And this will also not work because `ActionType` and `WordType` are separate types, and enums do not allow inheritance which could possibly make this work for other return types.

If you cannot know the return type *at compile time*, then you would have to return `object` and interpret the result at run time, to see what value it actually is.

---

If you actually meant the return value `WordType.None` to be a value of the enum type `T`, then what you *could* do is always return the default for the enum. That way, you can have your method be generic with a custom handling for `ActionType`:

```
public static T GetWordType<T>(string word) where T : System.Enum
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ActionType))
    {
        // you know `T` is `ActionType`, so you can cast to `T`:
        return (T)(object)ActionType.None;
    }

    // since you don’t know `T`, you cannot refer to actual values on
    // the imaginary enum `T`; you can however use the default value
    // (which will be the value 0, by default the first enum value)
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry @poke, my bad, but I make an Edit missclick and change WordType.None to ActionType.Cancel, which is incorrect. The objective of return a Generic type is cause it can return diferent EnumTypes. Can you check my code again with the correct version which return diferent Enum type outside the if? Thanks! :D

Comment: Okey, so the problem is resumed in 3 statements:  "Enums do not allow inheritance", "don't return the generic value if you don't know at compile time, use object instead" and "evaluate the returned type outside the method". Really thanks poke! (and sorry for the Edit-mess)

Comment: @Lotan I have added a third edit to my answer which might be what you were going for.

Comment: Oh yes! that actually works! I was trying to cast only with the Generic like (T)ActionType.None, but do not works. Now with (T)(object)  it works. This is something related with boxing right?

Comment: It’s because the handling of the enum constraint isn’t that great. The compiler doesn’t know that it can cast an enum to `T`. For the compiler `T` could still be anything, so you have to make sure that you deal with a type that you can cast to `T` first.